# how does python regular expression group work

Tags: python, python-re

```
import re

string = "现在是北京时间10点43分"
pattern = re.compile(r'\D*(?P<hour>\d{1,2})\D*(?P<minute>\d{1,2})\D*')
result = pattern.match(string)
print(result.groupdict())
```

this is my code, the outout is {'hour': '10', 'minute': '43'}, it works normally

then I change the code

```
import re

string = "现在是北京时间10点43分"
# pattern = re.compile(r'\D*(?P<hour>\d{1,2})\D*(?P<minute>\d{1,2})\D*')
pattern = re.compile(r'^\D+(?P<hour>\d{1,2})\D+(?P=hour)\D+$')
result = pattern.match(string)
print(result.groupdict())
```

r'^\D+(?P\d{1,2})\D+(?P=hour)\D+$' conform to grammar requirements, but it does not work, result is None, why?

Answer (score 1):

`(?P=hour)` says that it expects to match whatever was *actually* matched/captured by the named group `hour`, *not* the *pattern* that named group was matching. So your alternate pattern would match `"现在是北京时间10点10分"`, where the captured group is 10 and it's repeated after, but not `"现在是北京时间10点43分"` where you capture 10 and 43 is seen later.